# Match on subdocument key in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given that I have a hash subdocument within my document, how can I match a value - `categoryId` (itself added using `$addFields`) - to the sub-document key - `categoryTypes` - in my aggregation pipeline:
ex:

```
{
   _id: $someId,
   categoryId: 2,
   categoryTypes: {
     1: "hello world",
     2: "something else",
     3: "still more stuff"
   }
}
```

I need to match `categoryId` (2) to key in `categoryTypes` (2). In essence I need to say:

```
$match: { categoryId: categoryTypes }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `$objectToArray`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {allKeys: {$objectToArray: "$categoryTypes"}}},
  {$match: {$expr: {$in: [{$toString: "$categoryId"}, "$allKeys.k"]}}},
  {$unset: "allKeys"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PeeFdfv0IRj)

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out that's simpler than I originally thought:

1- First changed the hash into an array which produced a subdocument which looks like `ARRAY: [ "0": {...}, "1": {...}, ...]`

```
// this is happening in $addFields stage
categories: { "$objectToArray": "$categoryTypes"}
```

2- Then in my `project` stage I did:

```
category: {
    $filter: {
        input: '$categories',
        as: 'item',
        cond: {$eq: ['$$item.k', "$categoryId"]}
    }}
```

Hope this helps others who may be looking for a similar solution.